# react-native - check expiration of jwt with redux-thunk middleware before every call to API

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk, redux-middleware

For my react-native app I need to make sure that before every fetch request to server the use-case below should be executed

**-> check the expire date of token that is saved to redux.**

**--> If token is not expired, app keeps going on with requested `fetch` to server**

**--> If token expired, app immediately makes new request to `refresh token` without making user knows it. After successfully refreshing token,  app keeps going on with requested `fetch` to server**

I tried to implement middleware with `redux-thunk`, but I do not know whether it's good design or not. I just need someone experienced with `redux` and `react` to give me feedback over my middleware code.

This is how I make requests to server oveer my app's component through dispatching the `checkTokenAndFetch` - action creater.

```
url = "https://———————";
requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
    }
};

dispatch(authActions.checkTokenAndFetch(url, requestOptions))
    .then((data) => {

    })
```

here is action creator -  `checkTokenAndFetch` located in authActions.js 
 file where my `actions` located

```
function checkTokenAndFetch(url, requestOptions){

        return dispatch => {

        if(authServices.isTokenExpired()){
            console.log("TOKEN EXPIRED");
            authServices.refreshToken()
                .then(
                    refreshToken => {
                        var arr = refreshToken.split('.');
                        decodedToken = base64.decode(arr[1]);
                        newTokenExpDate = JSON.parse(decodedToken).exp;
                        dispatch(writeTokenToRedux(refreshToken,newTokenExpDate));
                    },
                    error => {
                        Alert.alert("TOKEN refresh failed","Login Again");
                        Actions.login();

                    }
                );
        }
        else{
            console.log("TOKEN IS FRESH");
        }

        return authServices.fetchForUFS(url, requestOptions)
            .then(
                response => {
                    return response;
                },
                error => {
                }
            )
            ;
    }
}
```

Here is `isTokenExpired` and `refreshToken` functions that I call for case of token expire, located in another file named authServices.js.

```
function isTokenExpired(){
    var newState = store.getState();
    var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();


    var exDate = newState.tokenExpDate;
    return milliseconds>exDate*1000
}


function refreshToken(){
    var refreshToken = store.getState();

    return fetch('https://—————————', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + refreshToken.token
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response._bodyText;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        return error;
        })
}
```

and my `fetchForUFS` function in authServices.js to make a call to server after completeing token-check(refresh) stuff.

```
function fetchForUFS(url,requestOptions){

    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseData) =>{
        return responseData;
    })
        .catch((error) => {
        })
}
```

I've read tons of `redux-thunk`, `redux-promise` and `middleware` documentation and I'm yet not sure whether I am implementing middleware logic truly?

Comment: All credit goes this man :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982412/how-do-i-check-for-token-expiration-and-logout-user