# Auto logout after access token expires in react application

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, msal.js, react-aad-msal

I have a react application authenticating with Azure AD using [react-aad-msal](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad) library. The below code is working fine. But when the access token expires getAccessToken method automatically fetches the new access token and keeps the application going. But instead, I have a requirement to ask user to reauthenticate when the access token expires and if the user is Idle for the entire duration. Is there a way to do it?

```
  const apiAuthenticationParameters = {
    scopes: [config.appScope],
    forceRefresh: true,
  };

  const getAccessToken = () => {
    return AuthProvider.getAccessToken(apiAuthenticationParameters);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems no direct method to check the token if it is about to expire. You could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982412/how-do-i-check-for-token-expiration-and-logout-user) with middleware.

```
const checkTokenExpirationMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const token =
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))["token"];
  if (jwtDecode(token).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
    next(action);
    localStorage.clear();
  }
  next(action);
};
```

The default lifetime of access token is 1 hour, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens). You could call logout function after the time.

Comment: But this approach will logout the active user as well when the token expires. But I need to logout only if the User is idle. I missed to mention in my question, I have updated the question

Comment: You could add a judgment on whether the user is idle with [`react-idle-timer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer). Logout in this event `handleOnIdle (event) {
    console.log('user is idle', event)
    console.log('last active', this.idleTimer.getLastActiveTime())
  }`.