# React Redux User Logout on JWT expiration

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

I'm trying to create a realtime function that if the user's token is expired they would be logout automatically. I tried logging out the user if I got a `401 status code` but sometimes I do receive an error using that and I'm also be using `socket-io` on my the project cause I need to display data in real time.

I uploaded the sample project on github and so far [this is what I've done](https://github.com/nellartsa/reacthook-redux-logreg.git). It contains just the login/register/logout function

I also found this [how-do-i-check-for-token-expiration-and-logout-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982412/how-do-i-check-for-token-expiration-and-logout-user) but I don't know how to wrap the function on `applymiddleware`.

And one last thing why am I getting `24 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 15 high, 1 critical)` on npm audit. I'm using `node v14.18.0` for this project

Comment: where do you save your token?

Comment: Looks like you have used create-react-app, so you are going to build the final source code and serve your app as static pages. Therefore you do not need to worry about most of the vulnerabilities, as you are not going to deploy those packages. I would still recommend that you check the extra packages you added yourself.

Comment: @Ifaruki I store then on localstorage

Comment: @hazimdikenli should I make react from scratch? Those vulnerabilities was already showing before I install other packages

Comment: @Nellartsa well why dont you store them in cookies? they have an expire date. you set the expire date same like your token expiration.

Comment: @Ifaruki I'm not really familiar using cookie, but I'll try creating one using cookie hopefully I could make it work